# "stub method" applied to EF CF requires all [Required] fields to be populated?

Tags: entity-framework

I was really happy to find the so called "stub method" to save DB lookups on update (among other things).  But when I tried it, and just populated the primary key field on my stub and nothing else, a whole bunch of validation errors showed up in my DbEntityValidationException that was thrown on SaveChanges(). Most/all of them were EF complaining about required fields not being specified, but am assuming I would also get dinged with referential integrity issues.

I had assumed (incorrectly?) that the stub method was a way for EF to 1) know what entity to update based on the primary key, 2) I didnt need to reload all the other fields I had not updated and  3) would only update those fields that I actually updated.

Im now pretty sure I misunderstood.  Too bad, the stub method was a cool concept.

If this is all true, then it appears I do have to retrieve the object first before updating it?

(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Stub method is cool concept but validation in EF is not. These two things don't work together. Either use full entities with all valid data and validation or stub methods and other improvements without validation.

You can turn off validation by calling:

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Comment: thats what I thought.  Thank you for the info on turning off validation in EF.  Will turning off validation also head off foreign key issues (ie, not setting the keys to acceptable values)?  Ie, if I only change simple properties, and dont fill in the references, am I still OK?
You mention "other improvements" - care to share some links or article please?  :-)